# ssrs 2008 tablix one column with fixed text while another column with dataset value

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-tablix

I would like to know whether tablix can fit in fixed text value in one column while the other column growth with dataset value.

Lets said I have a dataset query which return 5 values:

```
dummyvalue1
dummyvalue2
dummyvalue3
dummyvalue4
dummyvalue5
```

And I would like structure my tablix with one column, named 'ColumnA', to be fixed with text for 5 rows, and the adjacent column named 'ColumnB' to be filled with my dataset query, row by row.

```
|   ColumnA           |   ColumnB       |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow1'   |   dummyvalue1   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow2    |   dummyvalue2   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow3'   |   dummyvalue3   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow4'   |   dummyvalue4   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow5'   |   dummyvalue5   |
```

I have try to build the tablix but I always get all my dataset result squish in the first row only.

```
|   ColumnA           |   ColumnB       |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow1'   |   dummyvalue1   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow1'   |   dummyvalue2   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow1'   |   dummyvalue3   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow1'   |   dummyvalue4   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow1'   |   dummyvalue5   |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow2    |                 |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow3'   |                 |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow4'   |                 |
|---------------------|-----------------|
|   'myfixtextrow5'   |                 |
```

Can anyone please guide me or show the reference link for study? Thank you.

Comment: Does specific data correspond to specific data in column A?

Comment: No specific data, it just a plain text

Comment: To do this I'd set up each dummyvalue as it's own column in sql.

Comment: @jctan, create a calculated field in your dataset using `="myfixedtext"`

Comment: @Snowlockk, the text is text with certain format and arrange, which is no able to store in db. Besides, the db is no allowed to be modified.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, would it be able to hold more than one value?